# Thom's Principle: rich structures are more numerous in low dimension

Tags: ho.history-overview, gm.general-mathematics, big-picture

Marcel Berger states *Thom's Principle* as:

> "rich structures are more numerous in low dimension,
>   and poor structures are more numerous in high dimension."

This is in
*Geometry II*
(Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1987.

[Google books](http://books.google.com/books?id=iER421ZjkqcC&source=gbs_navlinks_s)), pp.39-40, after a discussion of regular polytopes
shows that there are only three convex regular polytopes in dimensions
larger than 4, but six in dimension 4, five in dimension 3, and
an infinite number in dimension 2.
He then lists further examples of the principle:
e.g., simple Lie groups illustrate rich structure in low dimensions,
and topological vector spaces illustrate poor structure in
high dimension (all homeomorphic in finite dimensions).

In so far as Thom's principle is true—or at least holds widely—my question is:

> *Why* should low dimensions exhibit richer structure
>   than high dimensions? Is there any generic reason to expect this?

It might also be interesting to track down Thom's own formulation
of his principle, to understand the context in which he proposed it.

**Edit.** Here is a snapshot of Berger's examples (p.40):

   [image: p.40]

Comment: Speculation: being low-dimensional beings, we care about things that are interesting/rich in low dimensions (but turn out to be poor/less interesting in high dimensions). That is, we are talking about a kind of selection bias here.

Comment: Sort of vaguely related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/5372/dimension-leaps

Comment: One way to say it is that in low dimensions there are richer structures. The other way is to say that in low dimensions there are more "exceptions" to the rules, as the "rules" start to get into their characteristic pattern only after some "low dimensional adjusting oscillations"...

Comment: I kind of question the premise.  "Rich" structures often arise when we classify an object and find that it comes in several infinite families with finitely many exceptional examples.  The exceptional examples are by their very nature often the most interesting, and we try to understand them by fitting them to our low-dimensional tools.  For example, the exceptional Lie group E8 has dimension 248 (is that low or high?) but thanks to the theory of root systems we can say a lot about it by doing algebra and geometry in 8 dimensional Euclidean space.

Comment: Aside from that, there are plenty of examples which at the moment are not expressible in what could possibly be considered low dimensions.  Last I checked the smallest known representation for the monster group is in dimension 196883, for example.

Comment: @PaulSiegel: "248 (is that low or high?)": I'm not sure the OP meant "low dimensional" in the geometric topology technical sense i.e. 1, 2, 3, and 4. I interpreted it more generally as meaning "phenomena that *only* occur within a bounded range of dimensions", so in this sense 248 is low.

Comment: On the other hand, one can reasonably argue that the most natural faithful representation of the monster simple group is infinite dimensional: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monster_vertex_algebra  Similarly, one has a "straightforward" construction of the E8 group using the vertex algebra of the E8 lattice.

Comment: I suppose this principle is tautological if you interpret "low dimension" sufficiently broadly.  Most of the mathematics we see does not live in dimension large enough to need assumptions of existence of large cardinals.

Comment: What do "rich" and "poor" actually mean??  For example, why are TVS considered "rich" in low dimension?  The message seems to be they are pretty uninteresting in low dimension!

Comment: @ToddTrimble, the quoted excerpt says, as you predict, that TVS are 'poor'.

Comment: @ToddTrimble: Maybe "poor" is not the ideal adjective. Thin, unvariegated, uniform, simple, ...

Comment: @LSpice Oh, I guess I misinterpreted the meaning. Thanks!

Comment: @LSpice On the other hand, I strongly dispute that it makes sense to call TVS "poor structures" (or unvariegated, simple, etc.). Same for fields.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One possible reason is that in higher dimensions there are more degrees of freedom that can be used to unravel and untangle things, which often leads to simpler structures. This reason has particularly been used as an explanation as to why the geometry/topology of high-dimensional manifolds is sometimes easier to deal with than that of lower dimensional ones. The canonical illustration that accompanies the previous sentence is the failure of the Whitney trick in dim < 5; the fact that the trick holds in higher dimensions was, for example, instrumental in Smale's proof of the $h$-cobordism theorem.

Comment: I'm glad someone mentioned Whitney and cobordism!

Answer (score 10):

#### Pro

I think the examples given are instances of Guy's "strong law of small numbers". That seems at least poetic reason for low-dimensional specializations of your favorite theory to be different in character from high-dimensional specializations.

#### Con

An example of increasing richness indicating Thom was thinking about something else:

- "The" connected 0-manifold is a point
- "The" connected compact 1-manifold is a circle
- Connected compact 2-manifolds are connect sums of tori or of projective planes; they are uniformizable.
- Connected compact smooth 3-manifolds are piecewise geometrizable, where the joints are among spheres and tori.
- Connected compact $(3+n)$-manifolds "solve" the word problem for groups; particularly weird: there are smooth examples that have contractible stable closed periodic geodesics in *any smooth metric*.

This is sort-of what I'd call *rigidity* in low dimensions, and *richness* in high dimensions. Perhaps the *theories* in low dimension are richer in the sense that there are more universal statements we can prove, but there seems to be a greater wealth of useful examples in higher dimension.

Whether this is an instance of Thom's principle as quoted or an exception, it is still an instance of Guy's law, in that the low-dimensional behaviour isn't representative of high-dimensional behaviour.

Comment: I never heard of Guy's "law"! :-) Thanks! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_Law_of_Small_Numbers

Answer (score 4):

I am reminded of the fact that for geometries of dimension strictly higher than 2, the Desarguesian and Pappian configurations are equivalent, so that (in my view) there is a greater degree of uniformity in higher dimensional geometric spaces.  I think Thom's principle (as noted in another post) is a selection principle and tells the reader what Thom thinks of by rich structure.  If structures are essentially (in mathematical logic, some notion of conservative) extensions of incidence relations, then I am not too surprised that something like this principle should hold, since a certain amount of uniqueness is lost in a structure that should be invariant under more geometric transformations.  I am not a geometer, though, so go ask someone like Hrushovksii what they think (from a mathematical logic perspective) of Thom's principle.

Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.09.13